# R plot_ly plot content changes as window size changes

Tags: r, scale, plotly

I have a scatter plot in plot_ly. Normally the data is made of 50 rows. When I plot it and zoom in, if it is full window size, I see every row, but when it is a smaller window size, a number of rows disappear according to the window size although their dots remain. Here is the small window size version

[image: Here is the smaller window size]

and once I increase the window size, I see the full data.

[image]

here is my code;

`p_alt <- plot_ly(data=cell_melt, x = cell_melt$value, y = cell_melt$gene_id, orientation = "h", type = "scatter", 
                   color = cell_melt$variable, hoverinfo = "text") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = rev(top_50$gene_id), margin = top_50$gene_id )) %>%
  layout(showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l=50, t=1, b=100))`

My ultimate goal is to get the full data plot regardless of the window size. What parameters do I need to use to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

While searching for solutions, I realized that there is a parameter `layout(yaxis = list(dtick = 1))` that makes every data point plotted independent of the window size.